# Getting the JOB_ID variable in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, jobs, kettle

When you log a job in Pentaho Data Integration, one of the fields is ID_JOB, described as "the batch id- a unique number increased by one for each run of a job."

Can I get this ID? I can see it in my logging tables, but I want to set up a transformation to get it. I think there might be a runtime variable that holds an ID for the running job.

I've tried using the Get Variables and Get System Info transformation steps to no avail. I am a new Kettle user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have batch_ids of the current transformation and of the parent job available on the Get System Info step. On PDI 5.0 they come before the "command line arguments", but order changes with each version, so you may have to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the variable yourself to house the parent job batch ID.  The way to do this is to add another transformation as the first step in your job that sets the variable and makes it available to all the other subsequent transformations and job steps that you'll call from the job.  Steps:

1) As you have probably already done, enable logging on the job
JOB SETTINGS -> SETTINGS -> CHECK: PASS BATCH ID
JOB SETTINGS -> LOG -> ENABLE LOGGING, DEFINE DATABASE LOG TABLE, ENABLE: ID_JOB FIELD

2) Add a new transformation call it "Set Variable" as the first step after the start of your job

3) Create a variable that will be accessible to all your other transformations that contains the value of the current jobs batch id

3a) ADD A GET SYSTEM INFO STEP.  GIVE A NAME TO YOUR FIELD - "parentJobBatchID" AND TYPE OF "parent job batch ID"

3b) ADD A SET VARIABLES STEP AFTER THE GET SYSTEM INFO STEP.  DRAW A HOP FROM THE GET SYSTEM INFO STEP TO THE SET VARIABLES STEP AS ITS MAIN OUTPUT

3c) IN THE SET VARIABLES STEP SET FIELDNAME: "parentJobBatchID", SET A VARIABLE NAME - "myJobBatchID", VARIABLE SCOPE TYPE "Valid in the Java Virtual Machine", LEAVE DEFAULT VALUE EMPTY

And that's it.  After that, you can go back to your job and add subsequent transformations and steps and they will all be able to access the variable you defined by substituting ${myJobBatchID} or whatever you chose to name it.

IT IS IMPORTANT THAT THE SET VARIABLES STEP IS THE ONLY THING THAT HAPPENS IN THE "Set Variables" TRANSFORMATION AND ANYTHING ELSE YOU WANT TO ACCESS THAT VARIABLE IS ADDED ONLY TO OTHER TRANSFORMATIONS CALLED BY THE JOB.  This is because transformations in Pentaho are multi-threaded and you cannot guarantee that the set variables step will happen before other activities in that transformation.  The parent job, however, executes sequentially so you can be assured that once you establish the variable containing parent job batch ID in the first transformation of the job that all other transformaitons and job steps will be able to use that variable.

You can test that it worked before you add other functionality by adding a "Write To Log" step after the Set Variables transformation that writes the variable ${myJobBatchID} to the log for you to view and confirm it is working.